# GWT Simple Drag and Drop for custom widgets

Tags: gwt, drag-and-drop

Are there any GWT gurus out there who can guide me on how to start with Drag and Drop in GWT for custom widgets. I have a build a simple tree structure by putting custom widgets inside an HTMLPanel (table rows) and want to be able to drag and drop each widget above or below other widgets but don't know where to start I am using 1.6. I need someone to guide me or point me in the right direction. thanks

Answer (score 7):

[gwt-dnd](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-dnd/) providing easy to use drag-and-drop capabilities to Google Web Toolkit (GWT) projects.
I encourage you for using this library. You can see a complete demo with source code about gwt-dnd in this site .

Comment: this is the only one out there, but it's design is quite questionable, lots of units are private or package private, while they clearly need to be protected for extending. Prepare yourself for some heavy copy/paste action.

Answer (score 1):

You can also look at drag-and-drop plugin of gwtquery.
documentation : http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery-plugins/wiki/DragAndDropPluginForGWTDeveloppers